# Which gerber files I need to send to my PCB manufacturer?

Tags: altium, pcb-fabrication, gerber

My PCB has two layers. I'm using altium and, after to generate the gerber files, I will to generate the drill files and send to a PCB's manufacturer.  But, about mechanical gerber files extensions, GM1, GM13 and GM15, I always get confused, I never know if I need to add them to all plots or not. So, I'll choose them in the two columns as can be seem on the figure below.

[image]

Is there some risk of doing that ? I mean, is there a problem to mark the mechanical layers in both sides ?

Comment: Why are you asking us, and not the manufacturer?

Comment: Copper layers, solder mask (not solder paste), and silk screens are the minimum. Plus the drill file. Also the routing layer. Anything you want to physically appear on the board. But PCB houses are not mindless. You can talk to them and give them specific notes.

Comment: @DaveTweed . I asked the manufacturer two days ago. But they did not answer me yet. And I need to send it to the responsible sector in my company, so they can give the order of fabrication and send it to the manufacturer.

Comment: If you're doing this for your employer, don't they have a process defined? Again, you should ask them, not us! Surely someone in your company has dealt with this vendor before.

Comment: Use a supplier with the required files on it's web site.

Comment: @DaveTweed, no, they don't have a process defined. The only responsible for it is me. There is a person that could help, but this person is rarelly available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what is on the mechanical layers, obviously. You could end up with copper (or ink) where you don't want it.

Generally you should **de-select** the "add to all plots" for all mechanical layers, and send a mechanical layer containing only the outline (or routing, V-groove etc. instructions) separately. I use GM5 or GM3 because it does not conflict with other stuff out there. I believe those particular layers are not enabled by default.

You should thus have a total of 8 files (7 gerber and one text) including the drill file for a simple 2-layer board (assuming you're not buying stencils for the paste layers). I don't think it's good practice to send unnecessary files.

Comment: +1, there are some manufacturers that ask to plot the outline on all layers. Not that this makes this answer any worse, more to drive Dave Tweeds point home: ask the manufacturer.

Comment: copper, mask, silkscreen for both layers plus drill and route files, and text instructions.  9 files.  Could you list what your 8 files are?

Comment: @scorpdaddy Copper x 2, Mask x 2, Overlay x 2, Outline, Drill file. For 2-layer boards ordered online (via form)  you usually don't need a readme file and often they will ignore it if you do include it.

Answer (score 2):

It can vary from manufacturer to manufacture, most have a guide on their website on how to send files, or they can be contacted directly.

At minimum for a two layer board the manufacturer will need top and bottom copper (GTL and GBL), a drill file and a board outline which is in one of the mechanical layers and that depends on how you've set altium up.

A four layer design will have two additional files for the inner layer copper.

If you want soldermask on your board, then the manufacturer will need soldermask files (GTS and GBS)

The silkscreen is contained in the GTO and GBO files.

The paste mask files are for assembly, and show where to put solder paste, many manufacturers provide the option for a stencil for solder paste assembly.

To ensure the board is manufacutered properly, it's also good to provide a layer stack up either in a [table generated by altium](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/PCB_Obj-LayerStackTable((Layer+Stack+Table))_AD) in a mechanical layer, or in a readme file
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**In a nutshell:**

To avoid confusion, it is usually smart to only plot the one mechanical layer which hosts exclusively the PCB outlines to all plots.

Other mechanical information like V-Grooves, or mechanical design date should be redirected to their own output and hence not be confused with copper layers.

**But in general:** 
Follow the guidelines of your specific PCB manufacturer.